# Async Sorting (using Tasks) in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, f#, task

I'm building an interpreter and need to create a function in my standard library that sorts based on a user-defined comparator. This comparator must be async, so this requires a sorting function itself is async (using `Task`s).

Is there an existing .NET sorting function that allows Tasks in the comparer? That is, the comparer returns a `Task<int>` and the sorting function completes the `Task` and uses the `int` to sort.

For example, a version of the [`List.Sort(IComparer<T>`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_Sort_System_Collections_Generic_IComparer__0__) function where [`Compare(T,T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=net-5.0) returned a `Task<int>` instead of an `int`.

(I'm using F# but happy to use C# libraries)

Edit: imagine the comparer needed to make a HTTP POST to compare two items.

Comment: You can't compare uncompleted tasks - as an analogy, if you've ordered pizzas from two different restaurants, you can't compare which one is hotter until they've been delivered...

Comment: Right, the sorting library would need to bind the tasks and then continue sorting once they are both done.

Comment: That would be an odd thing (IMO) for the sorting code to do. I think it would be more usual to wait *outside* the sorting code, obtaining the collection of results (instead of tasks) and then sort the results. If you really need to keep the tasks for some reason (although that seems odd to me as well), you could write your own `Comparer<Task<int>>` or `Comparison<Task<int>>` which checked the result - but you'd still need to make sure all the tasks had completed first.

Comment: You could write this, but what _sorting library_ would consume it?  Most sorting relies on contracts between the sorting algorithm and the comparison mechanism

Comment: I recognize that it's odd - I put the use case (language implementation) in the description. I unfortunately can't limit users to only synchronous comparators because the entire runtime is task based.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't need to keep the results of the `Task<int>`, I want the sorting library to consume it to know how to sort.

Comment: It knows how to sort, but why should it know how to wait for tasks to complete? Would you expect it to know how to request user input, as well? How to make a web request? These are all things outside the scope of a sorting algorithm. Most importantly, the `Sort` method is synchronous, but you want something which is inherently asynchronous. As I said before, you could wait for all the tasks to complete in your code, and pass in a comparison which uses `Task.Result` - but I definitely wouldn't expect the sorting code to do that, or for the comparison to do the waiting itself.

Comment: Right, that's why I'm asking for a sort function that's task-based, to see if SO have come across one before.

Comment: If you're trying to sort a huge number of things and you want to be able to sort the already-completed tasks while waiting for others to complete (in order to parallelize the sorting with the tasks themselves), that's a different matter (and one that you should make clear in the question). I would expect that to be pretty fiddly code to write efficiently. In any other case, I'd just wait for everything to complete, *then* sort.

Comment: To be clear, it's not the array which is in a Task, it 'sthe comparator that returns Tasks. That means we can't wait until everything completes before starting - the Tasks are produced as we attempt to sort, as part of the comparisons during the sort. (updated the question to try and make all this clearer)

Comment: If you really want to do this (knowing the evidence that you probably shouldn't) then  `Compare(T,T)` does not need to be async, if you are making an async call, just run the async code synchronously (i would strongly advice against this), however there is nothing stopping you.. If you really want to write a true async comparer, you are out of luck, it cant be done, there is no facility to do this, you will have to write your own and ignore what is provided for you in the BCL.

Comment: Yeah, no. I would define an api that returns some sortable primitive. eg `.OrderBy(async x => await x.GetDisplay())`. Collect the answers for the entire list, then sort. If every comparison involves a http request, sorting could create between O(n log n) and O(n^2) requests.

Comment: @jeremyLakeman You can't collect the answers in advance in a comparison-based sort

Comment: @PaulBiggar why? Just compare all pairs first and store results. O(n^2) complexity but definitely can be done.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ah yes, I meant if you want to keep the complexity the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could implement an async *mergesort* implementation that would do that.

And in fact, the Wikipedia article on [*Mergesort*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) actually discusses parallel implementations.

The basic algorithm is simplicity itself:

- Start with a list of items to be sorted
- If its length is 0 or 1, you're done: they are already sorted by definition.
- Partition that list into two halves
- Recursively merge sort each half, and then
- merge them together.

If your list is a linked list, no extra memory is needed, as the `next` point provides all that's needed.

If your list is an array-like construct, then you have to eat extra memory to create working arrays for each half as an in-place merge is not very practical.

**Edited to note:** Here's a little paperlet from Microsoft on implementing a .Net parallel mergesort with multiple partitions, not just 2: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/parallel-merge-sort-using-barrier/

Comment: Yeah, it looks a bit like i might have to.

Comment: Ended up not being too hard https://github.com/darklang/dark/commit/88a704a8df58d1b3da61f67563f4938bf2eaf3d7